# Como usar uma font Google na hora de imprimir?

Tags: css, font

Estou usando essa fonte:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script" rel="stylesheet">
font-family: 'Meie Script', cursive;
```

Ela funciona normalmente na página.
Porém na hora de imprimir a fonte não sai na pré-visualização e nem na impressão. Estou usando a função `print()` do *javascript*.
Tem como usar uma *font google* na impressão?

EDIT:

O *CSS*:

```
<style>
.nomes {
    font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive !important;              
}
</style>
```

A *div*:

```
<div class="row nomes">
    <div class="container nome-aluno">
         Thiago
    </div>
</div>
```

O botão de imprimir:

```
<button class="imprimi-certificado btn bg-green waves-effect">
   <i class="material-icons">print</i>
</button>
```

A função *JQuery* que imprime:

```
$('body').on('click', '.imprimi-certificado', function(){         
     var printContents = $(".cert").html();
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;         
     var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow","width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");    
    WindowObject.document.writeln("<style>.cert{display:block}.tabela tr td{border-bottom:2px solid #111;}.pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }</style>");
    WindowObject.document.writeln(printContents);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close();
});
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza se com a fonte vai ajudar, mas tenta utilizar o **media="all"**, ex.: **<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script" rel="stylesheet" media="all" >**

Comment: Testei e parece funcionar perfeitamente (http://output.jsbin.com/qakudiwibe). Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando o problema?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss realmente assim funciona, porem se eu especificar que quero somente que imprima uma diva especifica a font nao funciona nela. Ex: .classe{
  font-family: 'Meie Script', cursive;
}

Comment: Então, por isso o [mcve]. Faça-o que será mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a pergunta

Comment: E aí está o problema: você está carregando o conteúdo que será impresso em outra janela (`window.open`), mas em nenhum momento você carregou a fonte nela.

Comment: Colocar esse link <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script" rel="stylesheet"> no writeln da funcao é o correto?

Answer (score 1):

Tudo o que você inserir na função `writeln` será o HTML resultante na nova página para imprimir. Na função de *print* você adicionou os estilos para a impressão, porém não chamou a fonte desejada. Portanto, você deve chamá-la novamente. Você pode chamar a fonte usando a *tag* `<link>` ou fazer isso no próprio CSS com o `@import`.

Tente chamar assim a fonte:

```
WindowObject.document.writeln("<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rouge+Script\" rel=\"stylesheet\">");
```

...e adicionar novamente no CSS a fonte que deverá ser usada, fazendo:

```
WindowObject.document.writeln("<style>.cert{display:block}.nomes{font-family:'Rouge Script', cursive !important;}.tabela tr td{border-bottom:2px solid #111;}.pagebreak{page-break-before: always;}</style>");
```

**Obs.:** foi adicionada (por você) uma *tag* `<style>` no `writeln` e visto que ela normalmente é inserida no `<head>`, assim como o `<link>`, então não há problemas em chamar a fonte nessa função.